# C++ local container

Tags: c++, function, variables, containers

In C++ when I use array with determined size like: `int a[10000];` in a function as a local variable, the allowed size is smaller than if I declare it as global variable.

I know this is due to the stack size of function.

But what about containers like vector, list, queue, stack, priority_queue, map, etc. ? Are they limited when being local variables like `int a[10000]`?

Comment: Those containers are limited by the heap, not the stack

Comment: `vector` etc... allocate their internal storage dynamically. The `vector` is in local storage, on the stack typically, but `vector` is little more than a couple of pointers to data stored elsewhere with very different size limits.

Comment: Depends on the system they run on.  They use dynamic memory allocation which is generally a bigger pool of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` has the same space constraints as C-style arrays do. All other standard containers allocate their memory dynamically, and are thus not limited by stack size.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the C++ standard containers (except for `std::array` in C++11) will allocate the memory on the heap.